# Magento 2 CleverSoft theme Modules conflicting with other theme instaled on another website on the same magento Installtion

Tags: magento2, theme, multi-website, multi-vendor, conflict

Good Evening everyone,
I configured two websites on Magento 2. and set two different themes to the Websites. First theme was running Fine but when I Installed the another theme which is CleverSoft Moza on another website then Theme confliction come in notice.

I found that CleverSoft_Base Module which is defined under the Theme directory is conflicting with another theme, as their is no option to set that module for particular website. It is conflicting with the JS of first website on product page and i seen in the first theme that all cleversoft static modules are presented that cause the main confliction. On removing these modules from static directory under first theme some of confliction is solved while another remains. but when i deploy static content again it backs to the directory.

Now I want to make that module available only to that website but there is no default option provided by the vendor. Please let me know How i can deploy a particular module to particular website so that it doesn't conflict with another website on same magento installtion.

Comment: I can only tell you that the developer needs to use plugins to implement there coding. This is a developers error. Cheap themes and modules intent to conflict. You can not disable a module for a certain website. One can only rework the code themself or create a support ticket where they bought it. My apologies to bring you this bad news. We often do this for our customers for modules that are not ours.

Comment: Thanks Buddy for your response. I Created a ticket but no such type of action taken by them.

Comment: Good luck with it! If you need help we can always take a look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask you theme vendor to provide support in this matter as you can not do anything else you have to change the whole bunch of code to setup per store view or website enabling disabling the module. 
 
This will increase the work. If you purchased the theme then simply go for support or refund options if they are unable to provide support. Most of the Vendor companies provide full refund in case of their module or theme is not working or not upto the requirements.